# How to move a livestream wallpaper behind desktop icons?

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, desktop, streaming, icons

I have recently put the International Space Station (ISS) live stream as my background via VLC. With some adjusting of the zoom i've managed to fit the live stream perfectly to my desktop but my desktop icons are behind the live stream wallpaper.

Is there any way to move the live stream back behind the desktop icons so it acts as a proper wallpaper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=104725) on the VLC forums, one of the developers says that while it was possible to show the desktop icons on top of a streaming background in Windows XP, it is not possible in Windows 7 due to technological differences in the operating systems.